# How to use telethon websocket on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, telethon

client = TelegramClient('Name', key.Telegram_id, key.Telegram_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=1379897604))
async def my_event_handler(event):
sign = event.text

client.start()       client.run_until_disconnected()

Hello guys
I'm trying to use telethon websocket on aws
My code works at my computer
But it doesn't work on aws ec2 instance
Of course I add http and https port, my code works on aws when I connect to chats that I made
But it doesn't work when I connect to chats that someoneelse made
Is there anybody can help me?
I try to fix this problem from two weeks ago, but I can't figure it out how to work it..

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Proper grammar is important on SO, as is formatting. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
will help.

Comment: [mre] will help describe what we need to know.